# how to send longitude and latitude to map application to show particular co-ordinates on map?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an application in which on clicking a button, or on changing place, or after a particular time, I am able to get longitude and latitude values. I want to use this values to show them on Google Map application. I am opening a map using intent to show location, but somehow its not showing cordinates which I am getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a working piece of code that I use in one of my apps. This code also includes a check to find out if the user has Google Maps installed on his / her device. If the check returns the app as *installed*, then the function will pass on the data to the app. If the check fails, it displays an AlertDialog informing the use that the app is not installed.

```
protected void showMap() {

    boolean installedMaps = false;

    // CHECK IF GOOGLE MAPS IS INSTALLED
    PackageManager pkManager = getPackageManager();
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        PackageInfo pkInfo = pkManager.getPackageInfo("com.google.android.apps.maps", 0);
        installedMaps = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        installedMaps = false;
    }

    // SHOW THE MAP USING CO-ORDINATES FROM THE CHECKIN
    if (installedMaps == true) {
        String geoCode = "geo:0,0?q=" + PLACE_LATITUDE + ","
                + PLACE_LONGITUDE + "(" + PLACE_NAME + ")";
        Intent sendLocationToMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse(geoCode));
        startActivity(sendLocationToMap);
    } else if (installedMaps == false) {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                CheckinsDetails.this);

        // SET THE ICON
        alertDialogBuilder.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        // SET THE TITLE
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Google Maps Not Found");

        // SET THE MESSAGE
        alertDialogBuilder
                .setMessage(R.string.noMapsInstalled)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setNeutralButton("Got It",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });

        // CREATE THE ALERT DIALOG
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

        // SHOW THE ALERT DIALOG
        alertDialog.show();
    }
}
```

This line of code mentioned below sends it to Google Maps and instead of displaying just the *Pin* also displays the location name.

```
String geoCode = "geo:0,0?q=" + PLACE_LATITUDE + ","
                    + PLACE_LONGITUDE + "(" + PLACE_NAME + ")";
```

*EDIT:* If you do not wish to display the *PLACE_NAME*, modify that particular line with: `geo:latitude,longitude` instead of the one used in the code block.

Check this link for further combinations possible, like *zoom* for example: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/g-app-intents.html

Comment: @PrashantRane: Glad to have helped. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
Double latitud = 37.40*1E6;
            Double longitud = -5.99*1E6;

            GeoPoint loc =
                new GeoPoint(latitud.intValue(), longitud.intValue());

            controlMapa.animateTo(loc);

            int zoomActual = mapa.getZoomLevel();

            for(int i=zoomActual; i<10; i++)
                controlMapa.zoomIn();
        }
```

where

```
 controlMapa = mapa.getController();

      mapa = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);
```

For more info: [MapView Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview)

Comment: i did not code for displaying map, but want to send co ordinates to existing Map application which we get on evry android mobile....

Comment: ¬¬' yes, i know .... controlMapa.animateTo(loc); when loc is position .... it is the same code than @Siddharth Lele but more easy way ... up to you ....

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+ ze.getCoordenada().getLatitude() + ","+     ze.getCoordenada().getLongitude();
Intent goZe = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
goZe.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(goZe);
```

you will get a prompt to use browser or Maps

Answer (score 0):

somehow, using this string on google

```
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+ ze.getCoordenada().getLatitude() + ","+     ze.getCoordenada().getLongitude();
```

while selecting google maps shows oposite longitude and latitude while the website is correct.

maybe i am using an old version of google maps

Answer (score 0):

```
public void showMap(long latitude, long longitude) {
    String geoCode = "geo:0,0?q=" + latitude + ","
                        + longitude;
    Intent sendLocationToMap = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoCode));
    if (sendLocationToMap.resolveActivity(getPackageManager())!=null){
        startActivity(sendLocationToMap);
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this,"No Application To handle the Request",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```